# ElasticsearchIntegrationTest with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, lucene, spring-boot, integration

I am trying to use ElasticsearchIntegrationTest (http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/integration-tests.html) for my Integration tests in a Spring Boot application.

```
@ElasticsearchIntegrationTest.ClusterScope(scope =ElasticsearchIntegrationTest.Scope.SUITE)
public class MyElasticsearchIntegrationTests extends ElasticsearchIntegrationTest
```

When I run this test, I am getting following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Version must be upgraded to [4.10.4] is still set to     [4.10.3]
at org.elasticsearch.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:229)
at org.elasticsearch.test.ElasticsearchTestCase.<clinit>(ElasticsearchTestCase.java:87)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$1.run(RandomizedRunner.java:553)
```

My dependencies are defined like this in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-test-framework</artifactId>
        <version>4.10.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And when I run mvn dependecy:tree

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                     
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ demo ---
[INFO] com.sebpc:demo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:test-jar:tests:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:4.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:4.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:4.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:4.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:4.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:4.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:4.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:4.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:4.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:4.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:4.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:4.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-test-framework:jar:4.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-codecs:jar:4.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting:junit4-ant:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting:randomizedtesting-    runner:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.11:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.11:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.10.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.11:compile
[INFO] \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
```

It looks like all the lucene related libraries are 4.10.4, not 4.10.3, that's why I am a bit confused with this error message.

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not define artefact dependency for elasticsearch unless you want to use specific version as it will be added automatically by spring data elasticsearch.

with latest spring data elasticsearch snapshot 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT you will get elasticsearch 1.5.2 which is latest version anyway.

suggestion : remove elasticsearch dependency from your pom and use transient dependency coming from spring data elasticsearch.

if you still want to use particular version then exclude elasticsearch dependency from spring data elasticsearch.